# Why is numpy.ndarray.T so much faster than numpy.transpose(numpy.ndarray)?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Recently I came across someone using `numpy.transpose` instead of `numpy.ndarray.T`. I was curious so I timed it:

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np

array1015 = np.random.rand(10,15)

def nptrans():
    np.transpose(array1015)

def npt():
    array1015.T

print(timeit(nptrans))
print(timeit(npt))
```

The results were:

```
np.transpose: 1.25864219666

np.ndarray.T: 0.720939874649
```

Why? Shouldn't they be doing the same thing under the hood?  Maybe `np.transpose` is doing some sort of error checking or something that slows it down?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the operations are so fast it doesn't really matter if one optimizes there!

```
%timeit nptrans()  # 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.11 µs per loop
%timeit npt()      # 1000000 loops, best of 3: 905 ns per loop
```

Optimizing this doesn't make sense except you would be doing millions of transposes and nothing else. Even adding them is much, much slower:

```
%timeit array1015 + array1015  # 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.55 µs per loop
```

and addition should be really, **really** fast!

However there is some overhead in `np.transpose` that isn't present in `np.ndarray.T`:

- `np.transpose` in the end calls the objects `.transpose`-method which means it has to look-up the method of the object and call it.
- To avoid repeating their code the developers packed the function that actually calls the method in a seperate function. => One more function call.

So the overhead you see is the result of 2 function calls and a `getattr`-call. The [`np.transpose` function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.12.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L504-L550) is actually python so you can see the overhead quite easily (I removed comments):

```
def transpose(a, axes=None):
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'transpose', axes)  # extra function call

def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
    try:
        return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)  # here it finally calls ndarray.transpose()
    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
```

Comment: I see.  Well the code in question was a neural network for a Udacity project, so it might make some difference, I'll have to check.